# Add an ellipsis to HTML text if it is too large

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to add an ellipsis (three dots) to a string if it is too large?

For example.

From:

```
This is a very large sentence.
```

To:

```
This is a ve...
```

It may be done using PHP's `wordwrap` on server side but at that time it is difficult to get the rendered size, so is there a better, standard way to do it on client side using JavaScript, HTML or CSS ?

Here I have included a picture just in case you do not really get what I am saying.

[image: Example.]
''

Comment: You should search before you ask this question. It's been answered hundreds of times

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/strlen http://php.net/substr

Comment: what is "too large" how do you define it? check for it?

Comment: You can also do this in CSS.

Comment: Down voted for zero effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ideal way would be to use [css text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property:

```
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;                
  overflow: hidden;  /* "overflow" value must be different from "visible" */                
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeEdwardPortillo in that case you can select this as an answer and upvote if you will

Answer (score 6):

Here is a PHP function to do what you want, where 10 is the number of characters to preserve:

```
function truncateString($string) {
    if (strlen($string) > 10) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, 10) . "...";
    }
    return $string;
}

echo truncateString("Short"); // Returns "Short."
echo truncateString("Long string is long."); // Returns "Long strin..."
```

This will only apply if you are generating your menu items using PHP. If you want to do it on the client-side with Javascript and/or CSS, you would not use PHP at all.

Comment: Pedantry: For anyone outputting directly into HTML where you want the ellipses to appear I would advise using the character code, ```&hellip;```, rather than ```...``` which is 3 periods, not an ellipses. Most fonts even render them slightly differently: … vs ... But most importantly it's an accessibility improvement.

Answer (score 3):

It would be pretty simple to make a function to do this.

```
function limitstr($str,$maxlength=20,$additional="...")
{
    return (strlen($str)>$maxlength)? substr($str,0,$maxlength).$additional : $str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript**

```
str = "This is a very large sentence."

if(str.length>12){
  str = str.substring(0, 12)+"...";
  }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n4qZj/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess by saying "too large" you mean "doesn't fit in its container". If so, the solution is in `CSS`. It has completely no relation with `PHP` nor `Javascript`.

```
.your_element {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't even remember this one.

Answer (score -1):

```
If (string is > than 6) {
append three dots
} else {
leave untouched
}
```

[php.net/strlen](http://php.net/strlen)

[php.net/substr](http://php.net/substr)

Helped me come to this conclusion.